# Its printing a extra zero at the end and I'm not sure why

Tags: c, random

It asks user for how man random numbers they wish to create and sort and for some reason its printing a zero at the end of the list and I have no clue why... It checks to make sure more than 1 number is entered and that less then 10,000 are entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10000

int randu(void);
void bubble(int a[], int num);
void swap(int*,int*);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
int numsor,y;
int randoms[MAX];
int x=0;

if (argc == 1){
    printf("How many numbers do you wish to sort? \n");
    scanf("%d", &numsor);

}
if (argc == 2){
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &numsor); 
}

if (argc > 2){
    printf("how many numbers do you wish to sort? \n");
    scanf("%d", &numsor);
}
while (numsor<2 || numsor>10000){
    if (numsor < 2){
    printf("Error please enter a number more than 2. \n");
        }
    else{
    printf("Error please enter a number less than 10,000. \n");
        }

    scanf("%d", &numsor);
    }

    y = randu();
    for(x=0; x<numsor; x++){
     randoms[x]=randu();
    }

    bubble(randoms,numsor);

    for( x = 0; x <= numsor; x++){
         printf( "[%d]\n", randoms[x]);
    }

}


int randu(){
static int seed=17;
seed=(25179*seed+13849)%65536;
return seed;
};



void swap(int *a, int *b){
int temp;
temp=*a;
*a=*b;
*b=temp;
 }


void bubble(int a[], int num){
int i,j;

for(i=0; i<num-1; i++)
    for(j=num-1;i<j;j--)
        if(a[j-1]>a[j])
            swap(&a[j-1], &a[j]);
}
```

Comment: Because you're doing `for( x = 0; x <= numsor; x++){` when you're printing the list. Replace with `for( x = 0; x < numsor; x++){`.

Comment: I am sure I saw similar code yesterday - or do I have de-ja-vous

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
for( x = 0; x <= numsor; x++){
```

should use `<`, since otherwise you will iterate one time too many.